# Count the number of times a letter appears in a word and put them in the following format:

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, count, letter

I have to create a programme that given a phrase counts the number of times a letter appears in each word and prints it this way:

Input:

```
i see it
```

Output:

```
[('i', 1), ('s', 1), ('e', 2), ('i', 1), ('t', 1)]
```

My code only works for the first word.Can you help me?

```
inicialString=str(input())

words=inicialString.split(" ")
def countTheLetters(t):
 for word in words: 
  thingsList=[]
  for x in word:
   n=word.count(x)
   j=x,n
   thingsList.append(j)
  return thingsList

print(countTheLetters(words))
```

My Output:

```
[('i', 1)]
```

I have tried to replace the return thingsList but then it only worked for the last word.

Comment: `collections.Counter(word).items()`

Comment: @timgeb you're missing a `list(...)` there...

Comment: Shouldn't the expected output contain `(i, 2)` instead of `(i, 1)` three times?

Comment: `str(input())` can just be `input()` since it always returns a string in Python 3.

Comment: No.It is suppose to be specific for each word

Comment: Why there are two contiguous `('i', 1), ('i', 1)`?

Comment: I am not allowed to use that because it wasn't taught in classes. @timgeb

Comment: @AnaHelenaVieira yeah, I was expecting that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're emptying `thingsList` each time through the `for word in words:` loop, so you only get the last word.

Put `thingsList = []` before the first `for` statement.

Comment: It worked! That was really helpful.I can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: Use more spaces as indentation, you also need to put `return thingsList` after your `for` statement, but still you'll have some letters occur multiple times for single words.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you return from your function as soon as you check first word, instead you should append result of your current word to some final list and return it after you process all words.

```
inicialString='i see it'
words=inicialString.split(" ")

def countTheLetters(t):
    ret = []
    for word in words: 
        thingsList=[]
        for x in word:
            n=word.count(x)
            j=x,n
            if not j in thingsList:
                thingsList.append(j)
        ret.extend(thingsList)
    return ret

print(countTheLetters(words))
```

Output:

```
[('i', 1), ('s', 1), ('e', 2), ('i', 1), ('t', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are resetting the 'thingsList' every iteration of the 'for word in words' loop and also returning the thingsList list after only 1 iteration.

```
inicialString=str(input())

words=inicialString.split(" ")
def countTheLetters(t):
  thingsList=[]
 for word in words: 
  for x in word:
   n=word.count(x)
   j=x,n
   thingsList.append(j)
return thingsList

print(countTheLetters(words))
```

Answer (score 0):

updated your code check it now

```
inicialString=str(input())

words=inicialString.split(" ")
def countTheLetters(t):
 thingsList=[]
 for word in words:
  for x in word:
   n=word.count(x)
   j=x,n
   thingsList.append(j)
 return thingsList

print(countTheLetters(words))
```